# Android system app in c/c++?

Tags: android, c, linux, arm, native

I'm experimenting with a rooted Android tablet. I need to run some system applications in C/C++ that can run as native apps with/without using the NDK. This would work like existing command line applications such as toolbox as a native ARM Linux executable. 
Is that a possibility?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can. And you can do it using the NDK which you make things easier to you , cross-compiling to all platforms supported by Android (ARM variants and x86). You just need to do like you would do to create a shared library for native Java methods. Just make sure you change the makefile to use `BUILD_EXECUTABLE` instead of `BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY` to create an executable. Of course you won't need the APK folder structure, just the "jni" folder.

**Tutorial**

Create the project folders:

```
mkdir project_folder
cd project_folder/jni
NDK_PROJECT_PATH=<path to>/project_folder
```

Create the Android.mk makefile in the `jni` folder

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := teste
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := teste.c

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

Create also your source code in the `jni`. In this case, you can see from above makefile, it is `teste.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main (){

    puts("Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

Now go up to your project folder and run ndk-build from there:

```
# ~/Downloads/android-ndk-r8b/ndk-build 
Compile thumb  : teste <= teste.c
Executable     : teste
Install        : teste => libs/armeabi/teste
```

Although it is output to a lib folder it is a executable, as you can inspect with `file`

```
#file libs/armeabi/teste 
libs/armeabi/teste: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped
```

Comment: OK, so will this run as a dalvik Java program? Can you point me to a tutorial on doing this?

Comment: this is supposed to build a ELF binary, regarding the tutorial, I'm working on that

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial. It's great. I'll try this and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. When you download the NDK you get a set of tools (compiler, linker, etc.), headers and libraries. It's not significantly different from other cross compilation environments.

Comment: Doesn't that still create an .so file which communicates with a Dalvik VM using the JNI?

Comment: Unless you instruct the cross-compiler to do so.

Comment: If you compile with the flags to build a .so, it builds a .so. If not, it doesn't. I'd suggest using your own makefile (or other build script) to take precise control over the tool command line.

Comment: This means I can write a C/C++ program, not a Java program and flag the compiler to make an executable for me. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, it means you can write a C/C++ program... the NDK is a cross compiler which, other than targeting the Android system, is not unlike the gcc / g++ you already use.

Answer (score 0):

The NDK comes with a cross compiler and enough of a freestanding programming environment (includes and libs) to port simple C/C++ applications to run as native Android binaries.  Check out the docs/STANDALONE-TOOLCHAIN.html file in the NDK for documentation. (It's available online at [kandroid.com](http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/STANDALONE-TOOLCHAIN.html).)

Comment: Good source but the question says "native apps without using the NDK". (which is not possible afaik)

Comment: Well, instead of using the pre-built NDK, you could always just [check out the matching Android sources from the Git repositories](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html) and add a program directory there.  Copy and adapt the Android.mk of one of the other binaries in there, the build the entire tree. :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the NDK does not have access to enough system services to write a complete app.  You'll still have to write the scaffolding of the app in Java, but you can write plenty of native libraries for the Java to call.